# Where can I find a all avp Pcap for Authentication-Information-Request?

Tags: pcap, diameter-protocol

Please share avp files regarding Authentication-Information-Request

Comment: To get responses you need to try yourself, and than share codes, you will get good responses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All AIR AVPs can be found in the "ETSI TS 129 272" specifications.

I've copied all AVPs from section 7.2.5:

[image: AIR]

{} are mandatory AVPs

[] are optional AVPs

Here is an example from a pcap (I removed MCC/MNC from relevant AVPs):

[image: AIR pcap]